# Delete function picks up CSRF value as path

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Sorry for the massive code but I figured just put everything related out there. The fix might be easy.

I'm using a filemanager app django-fileman and I'm trying to get it work. So the problems are the move to basket and delete functions. But I will show the delete function here because they probably have the same problem and are very similar functions. In the app you can choose a set of files and then click delete and it should delete all the selected files.

I copy pasted the code from django csrf documentation into my script.js document ready section. It got my copy/cut function working but not the delete. Still picks up the csrf value as path.

Question: Why does it pick up the csrf value still? How can I fix this in the easiest way?
(Using Django 1.3, but still have `csrfResponseMMiddleware` in use if it is of issue)

I have the app working fully. But I have to add `csrf_exempt` to the functions as well as the function that lists the files. Like so:

views.py

```
@permission_required('fileman.can_fm_list')
@rightPath(True)
@csrf_exempt
def ls(request, path=None):
    """ Render file list """
    path = toString(path)
    dirlist = []
    filelist = []
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        f = toString(f)
        file = File(f, "%s/%s" % (path, f))
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f)):
            file.isdir = 1
            file.size = "Dir"
            dirlist.append(file)
        else:
            file.isdir = 0
            file.size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, f))
            filelist.append(file)
        dirlist.sort()
        filelist.sort()

    buffer = listBuffer(request)
    for item in buffer:
        item.append(os.path.basename(item[0]))

    anonymous = False
    return render_to_response('list.html',
           {"pwd": path,
            "dirlist": dirlist,
            "filelist": filelist,
            "buffer": buffer,
            "anonymous": anonymous,
            "availableSpace": availableSpace(path),
        "forbiddenFolder": os.path.basename(path),
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))




Deletes a set of chosen files or folders.
@permission_required('fileman.can_fm_destruct')
@csrf_exempt
def destraction2(request):
    if request.POST:
        if request.GET.has_key('next'):
        next = request.GET['next']
    else:
        next = ''
    for key in request.POST.keys():
        try:
            fmoper.remove(request.POST[key])
        except Exception, msg:
            return raise_error(request, [str(msg)])
        if request.is_ajax():
            return json({"status": "success"})
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/list/%s' % next)
    else:
        return raise_error(request,
            [_(u"Empty form.")])
```

fmoper.remove

```
def remove(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return shutil.rmtree(path)
    else:
        return os.remove(path)
```

script.js

```
script.js (Code related to a delete function of files or folders)


function destButton(element, path){
    element.html('<a href="#" ' +
    'onclick="return dest_one(this, \''+nameFromPath(path)+'\', ' +
    '\''+path+'\');" title="'+gettext("Destroy")+'">' +
    '<img src="'+url_media+'/deletered.png"WIDTH=18 HEIGHT=18        alt="'+gettext("Destroy")+'">     </a>');
    return 0;
}

...

function dest(){
    if(confirm(gettext("Huomio! Operaatiota ei voi peruuttaa! \nOletko varma että     haluat    poistaa pysyvästi valitut?"))){
    $("#fileListForm").attr("action", url_destraction+"?next="+pwd);
    $("#fileListForm").submit();
}
    return 0;
}

...


function onSuccessRemove(data){
    if(data.status=="success"){
    currentE.fadeOut("slow", function(){
    currentE.remove();
    });
}
else {
    alert(gettext("Error.\nServer reports:\n")+data.msg);
}
    return 0;
}

...
# The document ready

// Ready!
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filelist > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
    $("#filelist > tbody > tr > td > .dir").each(function(){
    $(this).dblclick(function(){
    window.location=url_home+pwd+"/"+$(this).text();
});
});
$("#filelist > tbody > tr > td > .file").each(function(){
    $(this).dblclick(function(){
        window.location=url_view+pwd+"/"+$(this).text();
    });
});

$('.block > h2').each(function(){ $(this).click(function(){
    $('.block > .content').hide();
    $(this).parent().children(".content").toggle();
}); });

$("#filelist > tbody > tr > td > .file").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("onclick", 'fileClick($(this).text())');
});
$("#download").hide();
$("#clipboard").hide();
$.clipboardReady(function(){}, { swfpath: url_media+"/jquery.clipboard.swf" });

// Copied from django documentation

$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                 }
               }
             }
             return cookieValue;
           }
           function sameOrigin(url) {
               // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
               var host = document.location.host; // host + port
               var protocol = document.location.protocol;
               var sr_origin = '//' + host;
               var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
               // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
               return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
                   (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
                   // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
                   !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
           }
           function safeMethod(method) {
               return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
           }

if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I ended up looking at the querydict I got as request.POST and noticed it had the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" once in everytime causing problems. I ended up making an if statement to check for it and pass it. Works. Don't know if this is a good solution securitywise but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps unsurprisingly the following code is processing the csrf token cookie:

```
if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Try using your own cookie name, and if you need a request header, use your own name for that too.

Comment: You mean i should replace xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken") and getCookie('csrftoken') with something else? or?

Comment: You are making your own cookie (and if you wish, header). You can pick whatever names you like.

Comment: Ok, If I change either of those my copy/cut stops working immediately. And the delete method functions the same as usual. Picking up the csrf value.

Comment: So did I understand correctly to just change those names? Or is there a process to changing the cookienames? I viewed my page and it has a "csrftoken" cookie with the same value my delete picks up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your actual html. In any case, you do realise that you are passing your post keys to fmoper.remove (whatever that does)? If you have a CSRF key in the post request, that (along with everything else) will be passed to it.

Comment: Yes thats the part that I understand, so the solution is to somehow not pick up the csrf value as path? How I go about that is something I don't know... Maybe I understood the code that I copied from django csrf wrong. I thought it would exclude the csrf value but it seems it just makes sure the request doesn't get caught. I added the fmoper.remove() function. Can I somehow separate the csrf key in my code?

Comment: The solution is to only pick up your paths as paths.

Comment: I ended up looking at the querydict I got as request.POST and noticed it had the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" once in everytime causing problems. I ended up making an if statement to check for it and pass it. Works. Don't know if this is a good solution securitywise but it works.

Comment: This is a terrible technique. Just pick out the keys you need.

Comment: Yes I'm looking at the keys and picking out the csrfmiddlewaretoken key. Do you have a better solution, with some specifics? Here is a example: QueryDict: {u'AUTORUN_2.INF': [u'/home/aksu/Django/basedraft/media/uploads/useruploads/chrome/AUTORUN_2.INF'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'b5e44764de3d263a9087318013bf617c'], u'AUTORUN_1.INF': [u'/home/aksu/Django/basedraft/media/uploads/useruploads/chrome/AUTORUN_1.INF']}>

Comment: Don't use the filenames as keys. Use a key scheme like 'keyname'+str(counter) to generate your keys, then you can just pick out the keys you have created. At present, you're just picking out the one key you know you want to avoid.